# How to get the filepath of the user's profile picture using Python?

Tags: python, windows, winapi, ctypes

I want to get the filepath of the user's profile picture in Windows using Python.

I've found [the following approach in VB6](https://underc0de.org/foro/codigos-fuentes/(vb)(undocumented)-loadusertile()-obtener-la-imagen-del-usuario/):

```
Option Explicit
'KERNEL32
Private Declare Function GetVersion Lib "KERNEL32" () As Long
'SHELL32
Private Declare Function SHGetUserPicturePath Lib "SHELL32" Alias "#261" (ByVal pUserOrPicName As Long, ByVal sguppFlags As Long, ByVal pwszPicPath As Long, ByVal picPathLen As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function xp_SHGetUserPicturePath Lib "SHELL32" Alias "#233" (ByVal pUserOrPicName As Long, ByVal sguppFlags As Long, ByVal pwszPicPath As Long) As Long

Private Const SGUPP_CREATEPICTURESDIR = &H80000000

Public Function LoadUserTile() As IPictureDisp
    Dim sPath   As String

    sPath = String$(256, vbNullChar)

    Select Case (GetVersion() And &HFF)
        Case 5
            Call xp_SHGetUserPicturePath(0, SGUPP_CREATEPICTURESDIR, StrPtr(sPath))
        Case 6
            Call SHGetUserPicturePath(0, SGUPP_CREATEPICTURESDIR, StrPtr(sPath), 256)
    End Select

    sPath = Left$(sPath, InStr(1, sPath, vbNullChar) - 1)

    Set LoadUserTile = LoadPicture(sPath)
End Function
```

But I don't know how to translate it to Python using ctypes, as the functions used are not documented by the MSDN. I've found [this alternative resource](http://undoc.airesoft.co.uk/shell32.dll/SHGetUserPicturePath.php), though.

I've also tried to access [this folder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/bb776892(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN):

```
%ProgramData%\Microsoft\User Account Pictures\Guest.bmp
%ProgramData%\Microsoft\User Account Pictures\User.bmp
```

But there are stored the default profile pictures, not the current ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Listing [[Python.Docs]: ctypes - A foreign function library for Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#module-ctypes).

[[Airesoft.UnDoc]: SHGetUserPicturePath](http://undoc.airesoft.co.uk/shell32.dll/SHGetUserPicturePath.php) (and the referenced *SHGetUserPicturePathEx*) contains the exact needed info:

> Copies the users account picture to a temporary directory and returns the path or returns various paths relating to user pictures
>
> #### Syntax
>
> ```c
> HRESULT WINAPI SHGetUserPicturePath (
>     LPCWSTR pwszPicOrUserName,
>     DWORD sguppFlags,
>     LPWSTR pwszPicPath,
>     UINT picPathLen
> )
> ```

Although the table at the end of the page lists *Win 8.1* as the newest version, it also works on *Win 10*.

**Notes**:

- Needless to say that being not part of the public *API*, **it shouldn't be relied on** (except maybe for demo / learning purposes), as the behavior might change or it could completely disappear. **Don't use this code in production!**

*code00.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import ctypes as ct
from ctypes import wintypes as wt


SGUPP_DIRECTORY = 0x01
SGUPP_DEFAULTDIRECTORY = 0x02
SGUPP_CREATEPICTURESDIR = 0x80000000


def main(*argv):
    shell32 = ct.WinDLL("shell32.dll")
    SHGetUserPicturePathW = shell32[261]
    SHGetUserPicturePathW.argtypes = (wt.LPWSTR, wt.DWORD, wt.LPWSTR, wt.UINT)
    SHGetUserPicturePathW.restype = ct.c_long

    buf_len = 0xFF
    buf = ct.create_unicode_buffer(buf_len)
    flags = SGUPP_CREATEPICTURESDIR
    res = SHGetUserPicturePathW(None, flags, buf, buf_len)
    print("    SHGetUserPicturePathW returned {0:016X}\n    Path set to: [{1:s}]".format(res, buf.value))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {:s} {:03d}bit on {:s}\n".format(" ".join(item.strip() for item in sys.version.split("\n")),
                                                    64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
    rc = main(*sys.argv[1:])
    print("\nDone.")
    sys.exit(rc)
```

**Output**:

> ```bat
> e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q059927534>"e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.07.06_test0\Scripts\python.exe" code00.py
> Python 3.7.6 (tags/v3.7.6:43364a7ae0, Dec 19 2019, 00:42:30) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] 064bit on win32
>
>     SHGetUserPicturePathW returned 0000000000000000
>     Path set to: [C:\Users\cfati\AppData\Local\Temp\cfati.bmp]
>
> Done.
> ```

Related: [[SO]: Get user picture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9148220/get-user-picture).

Answer (score 1):

**Use this**:

```
import glob
import os
# Please change the <username> to your username
search_dir = "C:\\Users\\<username>\\AppData\\Roaming\\Microsoft\\Windows\\AccountPictures\\"
files = list(filter(os.path.isfile, glob.glob(search_dir + "*")))
files.sort(key=lambda x: os.path.getmtime(x))
```

So, you will have a python list `files` which will contain the list of files in sorted by '*date of creation*' order. You can access the latest account picture using `files[0]`

> I took some reference from [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168409/how-do-you-get-a-directory-listing-sorted-by-creation-date-in-python)