# stored procedure return value in management studio but not in c# code

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, active-directory

I have a stored procedure that uses a linked server (ADSI) to connect to active directory. It takes in a string/varchar guid and then returns the thumbnailPhoto attribute of the user out of active directory. I am trying to call this procedure from C# code, but it keeps returning null. I've tried to make sure that the guid being passed was correct so from debug, I grabbed the guid being passed into the parameter then tried to use that to run the sproc in management studio. The result came back fine, but when I do it from my application, I get null. Here's the code:

SPROC:

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[sp_GetPhotoFromADSI] 
                @GUID varchar(100)
AS 
                SET NOCOUNT ON 
                SET XACT_ABORT ON  

                BEGIN TRAN

                DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(600)

                SET @sql=N'SELECT thumbnailPhoto FROM OPENQUERY(ADSI,
                                ''SELECT thumbnailPhoto 
                                  FROM ''''LDAP://<GUID=' + @GUID + '>'''' 
                                  WHERE objectCategory = ''''Person'''' AND objectClass = ''''user'''''')'

                EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @sql

                COMMIT
```

C#:

```
private byte[] GetUserPhotoByGuid(Guid userNativeGuid)
{
    //dont judge me for not abstracting this
    var connString = "connectionStringCrap;";
    byte[] photo = null;

    using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
    {
        try
        {
            string guidString = userNativeGuid.ToString();

            //var realGuid = Guid.Parse(userNativeGuid);
            using (var comm = new SqlCommand("sp_GetPhotoFromADSI", conn))
            {
                comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GUID", guidString);
                var returnParameter = comm.Parameters.Add("@Output", SqlDbType.Binary);
                returnParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
                conn.Open();
                comm.ExecuteScalar();

                photo = returnParameter.Value as byte[];
                return photo;                       
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }

    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: This stored procedure doesn't seem to have any output parameters.

Comment: Just a thought: wouldn't it be **much easier** to access AD directly from your C# code instead of taking a detour through SQL Server??? See e.g. [this SO question on the same topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1978717/how-to-upload-an-image-file-to-active-directory-user-profile-in-c) for some pointers

Comment: actually yes and no. My original code is hitting it through DirectoryServices which is much easier, but we're finding that using SQL is much faster.

Comment: What's the GUID look like? I'd definetely second the advice do this directly via ADSI. There's no way SQL will make this faster

Answer (score 5):

The value will be returned by `ExecuteScalar()`.

```
Byte[] photo = (Byte[])comm.ExecuteScalar();
```

Comment: the photo ends up being a byte array of at least 31100 in length. What are my other options?

Answer (score 2):

You probably want the result returned by ExecuteScalar. But bear in mind that it can return only up to 2033 chracters.

Comment: the photo ends up being a byte array of at least 31100 in length. What are my other options?

Comment: Use [SqlDataReader:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getbytes.aspx)

Comment: I used sqldatareader before i tried this method actually. The problem was that it was returning null just the same. When I ran the query in management studio, the data came back just fine. When I stepped through it in debug, I was watching the enumeration and it showed that it had a result/record, but that record was empty. This didn't make any sense to me :/